# instruments[34247:1345307] Attempting to set event horizon when core is not engaged, request ignored

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I get this error during ui automation and am unable to resolve it.
This stops my automation flow ...

> instruments[34247:1345307] Attempting to set event horizon when core
>   is not engaged, request ignored

Comment: How are you launching instruments?

Comment: Can you update your question with the command you are trying to run, and possibly more of the console output?

Comment: i have the same problem. Hier is my command. instruments -w "DEVICEID" -t /PATHTOTEMPLATE/APP.tracetemplate /PATHTOAPP/APP.app -e UIASCRIPT "/PATHTOTEST/UITests.js"

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada any leads onto this?

Comment: @nullpointer Nope. Solved ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this message is related to the startup or shutdown of the individual processes that enable UIAutomation; nothing in your javascript code or environment really has an effect on it.  It's just a sporadic error that comes from somewhere in Apple's software.

Sometimes it happens at the beginning of the run (in which case your javascript code will never be executed), or at the end of the run (in which case your code has already run).  If you are seeing this error at the end of a test run and your code did not fully execute, then the real error is probably happening sometime before this -- you are just seeing Apple's error as well on the test shutdown.